# Имя события проблемы: CLR20r3 Сигнатура проблемы 04: mscorlib Сигнатура проблемы 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windbg

Проект: (WinForms, DevExpress, .NET FW 4.5) клиент для сервиса. Делался на Windows Server 2008 R2. Скомпилированый проект на этой машине работает. На машине с Windows 8.1 и установленной VS - тоже работает. На машине с Windows 8.1 без VS - не работает!
Выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Имя события проблемы:   CLR20r3
  Сигнатура проблемы 01:    Client.exe
  Сигнатура проблемы 02:    1.0.0.0
  Сигнатура проблемы 03:    58047f7c
  Сигнатура проблемы 04:    mscorlib
  Сигнатура проблемы 05:    4.6.1055.0
  Сигнатура проблемы 06:    563c0eac
  Сигнатура проблемы 07:    40fd
  Сигнатура проблемы 08:    0
  Сигнатура проблемы 09:    System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  Версия ОС:    6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Код языка:    1049
  Дополнительные сведения 1:    5861
  Дополнительные сведения 2:    5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Дополнительные сведения 3:    1318
  Дополнительные сведения 4:    13181ae637ac2592fac0ca2dd662cdcc
```

System.IO.FileNotFoundException - натолкнул на мысль что не находит какую то .dll. Для всех библиотек, для которых можно было, установил свойство "копировать локально" = true. Проблему не решило!

CLR20r3 и mscorlib - подвели к тому что, может чем то ФреймВорк не нравится. Установка .NET FW 4.6, установка обновлений винды, отключение и последующее включение компонентов .NET FW 3.5 и 4.5. - Не помогло!

С помощью вот этой [статьи](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oanapl/2009/01/30/windows-error-reporting-and-clr-integration/) пытался определить место где вылетает исключение.
Но к сожалению ничего не получилось....
Команды описанные в примере у меня не заработали. (в полне возможно из неправильного их использования!)

```
0:007> .loadby sos mscorwks
Unable to find module 'mscorwks'
0:007> !token2ee mscorlib 06000040fd
No export token2ee found
```

Запустил через WinDbg .exe и выполнил  `!analyze -v` , получил такой результат:

```
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Client.exe
GetUrlPageData2 (WinHttp) failed: 12002.

DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 0

FAULTING_IP: 
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+2b
77123c7d cc              int     3

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 77123c7d (ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x0000002b)
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 00000000

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000f14

PROCESS_NAME:  Client.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - {

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000

WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP:  58047f7c

WATSON_BKT_PROCVER:  1.0.0.0

PROCESS_VER_PRODUCT:  Client

WATSON_BKT_MODULE:  ntdll.dll

WATSON_BKT_MODSTAMP:  56bb4e1d

WATSON_BKT_MODOFFSET:  b3c7d

WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  6.3.9600.18233

MODULE_VER_PRODUCT:  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  6.3.9600.17415 (winblue_r4.141028-1500)

MODLIST_WITH_TSCHKSUM_HASH:  049de938cde16004d3def1c8a595a334e160586f

MODLIST_SHA1_HASH:  d5aa0548e0a0e33ed79e20de3a62e9bdc9b1ccb5

NTGLOBALFLAG:  70

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

SUITE_MASK:  272

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  TECHDIR

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  10-20-2016 00:27:11.0873

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 x86fre

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [ProcessUpTime] from Frame:[ffffffff] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD] ; Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 770f853c to 77123c7d

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  89f7b183a84958ac40c6d818861d72cb316fd6a3

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  3eede2065008e01cabea48725a58fa684c801148

OS_LOCALE:  RUS

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 



LOADER_INIT_FAILURE
    Tid    [0x0]
    Frame  [0x00]
    String [80000003]
    Data Bucketing


BUGCHECK_STR:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_80000003

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_80000003

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000 00000000 Client.exe!unknown_function+0x0


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  5e896533852c8e3b62be2d4b1d9e6cdc08d10c5e

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  Client.exe!unknown_function

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: Client

IMAGE_NAME:  Client.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  58047f7c

STACK_COMMAND:  dt ntdll!LdrpLastDllInitializer BaseDllName ; dt ntdll!LdrpFailureData ; ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_80000003_Client.exe!unknown_function

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_80000003_Client.exe!unknown_function

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  80000003

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  Client.exe

BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  Client.exe

FAILURE_MODULE_NAME:  Client

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  Client

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  unknown_function

BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR:  unknown_function

BUCKET_ID_OFFSET:  0

BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP:  58047f7c

BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM:  0

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  1.0.0.0

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_80000003_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_80000003

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  Client.exe!unknown_function

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_80000003_80000003_Client.exe!unknown_function

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/Client.exe/1.0.0.0/58047f7c/ntdll.dll/6.3.9600.18233/56bb4e1d/80000003/000b3c7d.htm?Retriage=1

TARGET_TIME:  2016-10-19T21:27:18.000Z

OSBUILD:  9600

OSSERVICEPACK:  17415

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows 8.1

OSEDITION:  Windows 8.1 WinNt SingleUserTS

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2014-10-29 03:58:22

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  141028-1500

BUILDLAB_STR:  winblue_r4

BUILDOSVER_STR:  6.3.9600.17415

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 6b88

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:loader_init_failure_80000003_80000003_client.exe!unknown_function

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {e7bd1b86-fd09-d247-c63c-daeceefef413}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Но разобраться в этом и понять почему вылетает исключение - не смог......
Может кто то знает как  решить эту проблему, ну или хотя бы сможет проконсультировать как узнать с помощью дебагера, где вылетает исключение...
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: DewExpress говорите... попробуйте посмотреть зависимости его библиотек друг от друга, вполне возможно, что вы явно на нее не ссылаетесь, но она нужна другим библиотекам.

Comment: 1) Проверьте что в референс все подключенные библиотеки DevExpress имеют флаг "Копировать локально = true" 2) Если используется тема оформления из пакета DevExpress - то библиотека конкретно этой темы должна лежать в папке Debug или Result, в зависимости от настроек проекта, т.е. должна находиться в каталоге вместе с вашим приложением. 3) Проверьте установлен или включен ли в компонентах .NET 2.0 или 3.5.

Comment: @rdorn - Добрый день. А как посмотреть зависимости библиотек друг от друга вы не подскажите?

Comment: @Alexis - 1) - у всех библиотек ДевЭкс установлен флаг "Копировать локально".  2) - по поводу тем, точно не скажу, но вроде бы темами не пользовался. 3) - в 8-рке можно включать и отключать только 3.5 (он содержит в себе и 2.0), 3.5 и 4.5 - включены.

Comment: можно посмотреть манифест через ILDasm, там в самом начале перечислены сборки, необходимые для работы исследуемой сборки.

Comment: @ rdorn - при открытии с помощью Dependency Walker любой .dll DevEx из папки Release ругается на библиотеку NTDLL.DLL! Цепочка зависимостей: DEVEXPRESS."Любая".DLL->MSCORE.DLL->KERNEL32.DLL->KERNELBASE.DLL->NTDLL.DLL(библиотека на которую ругается). Я так понимаю что ДевЕкспресовским dll-кам не нравится какая то либа из фреймворка?

Comment: ещё ругается на модули с разной разрядностью процессоров!

Comment: В SDK к Windows есть утилита FUSLOGVW.exe. Её может настроить, что бы она записывала все неудачные попытки найти сборку, там же будет информация о том, какую сборку и для какого класса пытались найти. Ещё, если ваш проект собран в отладочном режиме, можете попробовать посмотреть виндовый журнал событий  от приложение, там может быть стек вызовов в момент ошибки.

Comment: @Dmitriy Nemykin - FUSLOGVW у меня нету. В журнале событий, частенько мелькали ошибки в которых фигурировала всё та же NTDLL.DLL!

Comment: @Василий Хмеленко, есть ли у вас возможность изменять код и проверять поведение приложения на хосте с  Windows 8.1? Если есть то, попробуйте подправить ваше приложение, добавив в самом начале его работы подписку на событие об ошибках, происходящих в домене приложения, в обработчике события попробуйте добавить вывод (например в файл) дополнительной информации об исключении.

Comment: @Dmitriy Nemykin у меня WinForms клиент для сервиса. В начале его работы - это в конструкторе формы, или в Form_Load()? Просто в конструкторе формы у меня одна строчка инициализации компонента,  а в Form_Load() я инициализирую Soap-клиента для сервиса и настраиваю Binding.

Comment: @Dmitriy Nemykin Спасибо большое, ваш способ - помог отловить исключение! Говорит что не может загрузить DevExpress.Images.v15.1., хотя какая из Девовских либ её дёргает - не знаю.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть проблемы была в том что я использовал кучу библиотек DevExpress, и вот какой то из них(или всем сразу) не хватало другой девовской либы - DevExpress.Images.v15.1. После того как я добавил на неё ссылку, и установил "Копировать локально"= true. Всё заработало! Большущая благодарность @Dmitriy Nemykin за наводку!!!!!!